# Unable to find xcart page

Tags: php, smarty, x-cart

in our application we find a page like below

domainname.com/store_page.php

In the root folder, we can see store_page.php file.

Inside that page, it is loading that page from other location

$smarty->assign('main','store_page');

We are unable to track where this 'store_page' is coming from. We want to edit meta titles and other values in that store page.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was a while ago, but I'm going through trying to answer the x-cart questions on here.

Your info is stored in a template file within your "skin" directory.  Depending on your x-cart version you need to find the smarty template file (probably store_page.tpl) in this case.   These files are all .tpl and where you will find html and smarty tags.

When your store_page.php file has a line like $smarty->assign('main', 'store_page') all that is doing is simply assigning a variable in PHP for smarty to use.   In this case the variable $main will be available in the template and will contain the value of 'store_page'.

I hope this helps someone who may be having a similar question.